# jquery upgrade from 2.1.4 to 3.6.0

Tags: jquery, upgrade, migrate

I am trying to upgrade jquery from 2.1.4 to 3.6.0. I been going through the jquery migration here https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#jquery-migrate-plugin. I am new with this so am having a hard time figuring out how to upgrade jquery on our code. Can someone please advice and point me towards the right direction? Thanks.
When I check for errors this is what I get:
at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.hcCharts (scripts.js:37:66)

```
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:425:17)

at j (jquery.min.js:2:26925)

at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:27738)

at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2:29532)

at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js:2:29723)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziwQm.png)

Comment: That isn't a problem related to migrating from 2.1.4 to 3.6.0. More than likely, you have multiple versions of jquery on the page. Cleanup your script tags.

Comment: Yes on this page I have "jquery.min.js", "jquery.matchHeight.min.js", "jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js", "jquery.scrollbar.js", "scripts.js". I am getting the errors for scripts.js and jquery.min.js. Any idea what is causing this? Would these version require a different upgrade? Thanks for the help

Comment: That error states a plug-in isn’t installed. Upgrading wouldn’t cause that problem.

Comment: 0


I figured out what was going wrong. I had placed the jQuery upgrade scripts after the other 10 or so high charts javascripts...so at the end. I moved the jQuery upgrade to the top and I have no more errors. Thanks.